# Symfony2: How can I disable form cascade validation?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with one entity form field. When I call `$form->isValid()`, symfony validates the object associated to this field. I know that problem is [fixed](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/0c70a410e539486c1901e96201a9a863458034a6) (cascade_validation) for symfony master branch, but I use synfony 2.0.9. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem using validation groups.

Answer (score 5):

A `cascade_validation` option has been added to the master branch for explicit control over this, but there is nothing in the 2.0 branch.

Comment: then.. how solve this problem in projects based on 2.0 branch?