# Children types are not validated using isValid() in symfony2 forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem concerning validation of children of a form.
I have a type, that contain several types of another type.
In those subtype I have one field required, one fiend non required. 
But even both are empty, the form is validated
Here are my classes

```
  class PassengerList {

/**
 * @Assert\Valid() //If it's an array of objet, should validate all the object of the list *traverse
 */
protected $passengers;
/**
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $passengers_child;
/**
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $passengers_baby;
}
```

**passengerListType**

```
class PassengerListType extends AbstractType
 {
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('passengers','collection', array(
            'type' => new PassengerType(),
            'allow_add' => false,
            'required'=> true,
            'allow_delete' => false));
    $builder->add('passengers_child','collection', array(
            'type' => new PassengerChildType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => false));
    $builder->add('passengers_baby','collection', array(
            'type' => new PassengerBabyType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => false));

}
function getName()
{
    return 'passenger_list';
}

}
```

**PassengerType**

```
class PassengerType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $date_params = array("widget"=>"single_text","input"=>"datetime",'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',);
    $builder
    ->add('civility', 'choice', array("choices"=>Passenger::getCivilityList()))
    ->add('birthdate','date',$date_params)
    ->add('last_name','text',array('required'=>true))
    ->add('first_name','text',array('required'=>false))
    ->add('type','hidden');
}
function getName()
{
    return 'passenger';
}
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
            'data_class' => 'Travelyo\CoreBundle\Entity\Passenger',
    );
}
}
```

which give me this form:

[image]

But when validating the form with $form->isValid() The value returned is true altough I leave both fields empty.

I have the feeling that the problem is that nothing is validated in the chidlren types.

Do you have any leeds that can help me with that ?

Comment: Beware that Form::isValid method doesn't process validation, but only returns a boolean, set while validation has been processed (with bindRequest for a Form).

Comment: What does your Passenger class look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using 2.1?

Either you need to specify [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups), or enable [`cascade_validation`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/0c70a410e539486c1901e96201a9a863458034a6), similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233547/symfony2-how-can-i-disable-form-cascade-validation).

Comment: Still not upgraded to 2.1, working actually on 2.0.16.
I'll try to work with validation groups as cascade_validation doesn't seem to be valid in the 2.0.16.
Thanks

Comment: I tried to update Symfony in order to enable cascade_validation. It does go to those new function added. But my form is still considered as valid.
How exactly can validation_groups can help me here, as if the children are not validated, they won't be validated either if I'll separate by groups, Am i wrong ?

Comment: I don't recommend to use cascade_validation here, because the Valid constraint should work. There seems to be some issue with your code (e.g. in the Passenger class).